# What's the optimal solution for performance: Fedora's LXQt spin or install @lxqt using dnf?

Tags: fedora, lxqt

I am installing LXQt, so I can have something lightweight and fast.

To achieve this, I found the two mentioned approaches but I don't know how to decide on what to choose.

Also: is there a better solution which includes using LXQt as *desktop environment* for Fedora?

Comment: Perhaps if you gave some details about what you mean by "performance" someone may be able to respond more directly to your concerns and use case.  For example, are you concerned about speed (speed of what?), size (size of what?), etc.  "... I don't know how to decide ..."  Well, what would you measure to decide which is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. All Fedora packages in all spins are absolutely the same.
2. When you choose a spin you simply select a certain set of packages.
3. You can "transform" any spin into another one by uninstalling its packages and installing different packages.

---

In any Fedora distro you can do the following:

1. `dnf group install "LXQt Desktop"`

That will also install a huge number of weak dependencies which you might never need. If you wanna go without them,

2. `dnf --setopt=install_weak_deps=False group install "LXQt Desktop"`

Lastly you don't even need to install all the packages pertaining to a particular group. You may choose exactly what you need and go with it, e.g.

3. `dnf --setopt=install_weak_deps=False install lxqt-session lxqt-panel lxqt-about lxqt-globalkeys lxqt-notificationd lxqt-policykit lxqt-powermanagement lxqt-runner lxqt-config-randr lxqt-sudo`

The first command wants to install 1.7GB of packages on my system, the second one 1.5GB, the last one just 184MB. Either of these commands produce the same result in terms of performance, it's just the additional packages that might come in handy.

Comment: That's perfect! I wish I could adopt a similar approach to the last one mentioned... I'm just affraid it can take too much time to learn about it. I think I'll just go with the Fedora spin ISO, for the time being. Thanks, again!